# SSL doesn't work on FB App

Tags: facebook, ssl

I bought a cheap SSL (RapidSSL), with CA too. It's not self-signed.
Then I want to use it with my facebook application.
If I open my page outside the facebook, it says everything is okay with my SSL, but if I want to open my app in secure browsing, FB shows blank page :(

https://specialpromotion.hu/fb_kviz/

here you can see, that the SSL is working fine.

https://apps.facebook.com/estikviz/ and it works fine too, with this link. But my fb page shows blank only :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the HTTPS URL as the Secure Canvas URL, and the non-HTTPS URL as the Canvas URL field in the App settings
Note, you need to provide both; not just a HTTPS URL in both fields, or HTTPS only in the "Canvas URL" and nothing in the "Secure Canvas URL" field

Comment: I know, they are set like you said.

 [picture link](http://iaro.3dmax.hu/images/2012/03/29/fbapp.jpg)

Comment: Your page tab and secure page tab URL should be absolute URLS - I *think* it might be accepted as a relative URL for the HTTP version, but the HTTPS version won't work unless it's an absolute URL

Comment: Thanks your answer. I deleted the Secure Canvas URL(it's empty now), and I put the whole absolute link into 
"Secure Page Tab URL:" field. It's weird, but it works now :)

Comment: Canvas URL and secure canvas URL are the backing URLs for your apps.facebook.com/<something> address, page tab URL and secure page tab URL are the backing URL for when your app is installed to a page - if your app is accessed via both methods, you probably need all 4 of those fields filled in for it to work for every user